# How give trust to an external application accessing the Outlook Object Model (with all security options on)

Tags: outlook, com, outlook-object-model

I have a .NET application that interacts with Outlook like this:

```
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new
              Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem item = app.CreateItem((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem));
                item.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(PsInternetHeaders + Foobar, 1031);
                item.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
                item.To = "a@test.com;b@test.com;c@test.com";
                item.BCC = "cc@test.com";
                item.Body = "Hello There!";
                item.Display();
```

Be aware that I need to access the "PropertyAccessor" property.

In a normal environment this runs fine, but in a "secure" enviroment with this registry keys in place it just fails with `Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))`:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\outlook\security]
"PromptOOMAddressBookAccess"=dword:00000000
"AdminSecurityMode"=dword:00000003
"PromptOOMAddressInformationAccess"=dword:00000000
```

Outlooks security model seems to have a "trustedaddins" list, but I'm not really sure if this applies to "external applications" as well and that exactly I need to register unter `TrustedAddins` (see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/926512/information-for-administrators-about-e-mail-security-settings-in-outlo)).
My main question would be: Can I just register and foobar.exe unter `trustedaddins` or is this not possible at all?
I know that I could lower or disable the security stuff, but this is not my choice ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only options are listed at [How to avoid Outlook Security Alert when sending Outlook message from VBScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898756/how-to-avoid-outlook-security-alert-when-sending-outlook-message-from-vbscript)

You also might want to set `PsInternetHeaders` properties to strings only, not ints.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand this correctly: If there are "programmatic access policy applied" (+ the GPO setting) the cross process way is (besides the MAPI or ClickYes stuff) closed, correct? (Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/security/security-behavior-of-the-outlook-object-model)

Comment: If the user is using Exchange, it will be determined by the Exchange policy. Installing an up-to-date AV app is probably the easiest way if you don't want to wok around the problem programmatically (Extended MAPI in C++/Delphi or Redemption in any language).

Comment: The problem only occures with the "AdminSecurityMode=3", which we can't change :-/
Thanks for the answer.